# How to convert `bytes4` to `bytes memory` in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, bytes, function-selector

`bytes4` is a commonly needed data type in Solidity, due to its use in `msg.sig` and, more broadly speaking, in function selectors (e.g. `Contract.func.selector`).

How can one convert `bytes4` to `bytes memory`?

Comment: can we just use direct conversion ```bytes memory convertedData = new bytes256(msg.sig)```?

Comment: `bytes256` doesn't exist as a type. But, assuming you meant `bytes32`, no, you can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`abi.encodeWithSelector`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.18/units-and-global-variables.html#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions) can be used for this:

```
bytes memory a = abi.encodeWithSelector(msg.sig);
bytes memory b = abi.encodeWithSelector(Contract.func.selector);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly using `abi.encode()` or `abi.encodePacked()`.

```
function get(bytes4 _val) public pure returns(bytes memory) {
        return abi.encode(_val);
}
```

Example:

```
Input: 0x60c06040

Output: 0x60c0604000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```